# Problem with tag editing window

Tags: bug, design

I just noticed in editing a tag wiki entry the following interface "bug." Note that the text entry window overlaps with the "What is a tag wiki excerpt" text at right. Resizing the window does nothing to eliminate the overlap.

[image]

Comment: @balpha: Why isn't this also a "user-interface" issue?